# Paypal API for recurring payment based on usage

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

I am currently upgrading an old system writing in JSF, which communicates with Paypal to create an "Acceptance term" for recurring payment, it generates a Token and when the client accepts the term, it creates an Agreement Id, later we use these to charge the client based on the services he used.
On the Paypal developer website, the Billing Agreement API is marked as deprecated, so I can´t work with it, they offer the Subscription as an alternative, but it doesn´t give the Agreement Id or the possibility to charge the user based on the usage, at least, not that I´ve seen.
Is there a way to create the Token and Agreement, or to use the Subscription (or other methods) to charge the user based on that?

eg. We offer a mobile plan for U$ 10, plus U$ 5 if the user sends more than 1000 messages, we first check if that happened, then we charge the user.

Answer (score 0):

If the account is approved for reference transactions, and it sounds like it may be, you can use the Vault API which is in open beta, in conjunction with the orders API. See [this example](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/limited-release/vault-payment-methods/vault-api/#2-use-the-payment-token-in-a-transaction).